# Linq to XML - Searching for Existence of a Deep Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I simply want to check to see if a certain element exists in my XML file. The element is a few levels deep. The following code works fine, but is the shortest syntax I can come up with. Can anyone think of a way to do this more fluently without resorting to classic XPath syntax?

```
        //create simple sample xml
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("Bookstore",
            new XAttribute("Name", "MyBookstore"),
            new XElement("Books",
                new XElement("Book",
                    new XAttribute("Title", "MyBook"),
                    new XAttribute("ISBN", "1234")))));

        //write out a boolean indicating if the book exists
        Console.WriteLine(
            doc.Element("Bookstore") != null &&
            doc.Element("Bookstore").Element("Books") != null &&
            doc.Element("Bookstore").Element("Books").Element("Book") != null
        );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Descendants("Book").Any());
```

Comment: @mellamokb you are correct; I must have been thinking println from java while I was typing that.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work because I might have a Book anywhere. I need the specific hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

This would work - assuming you actually do need the exact hierarchy because they might be a `Book` node in an unrelated sub tree, otherwise you can use `Descendants()`:

```
Console.WriteLine( doc.Elements("Bookstore")
                      .Elements("Books")
                      .Elements("Book")
                      .Any());
```

The plural `Elements()` does not require the `null` check since it will just return an empty enumeration if no such element exists, so it is still chainable.

Comment: Great idea. I like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not shorter but:

```
var isBookExist = 
    (from store in doc.Elements("Bookstore")
     from books in store.Elements("Books")
     from book in books.Elements("Book")
     select book).Any();
```